# How can I replace an executable created by PyInstaller from within the code?

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I'm trying to automatically update my software when a new version is released. It can check for a new version and download it in a background thread with no problem. It then has two files next to each other - the original executable (currently running; created with PyInstaller), and the new executable binary blob.

What I want to do is `os.rename('update-temp.dat', sys.executable)` (`sys.executable` points to the compiled program when using PyInstaller, not the Python interpreter). This works fine on Linux, but not on Windows.

On Windows, just using `os.rename()` gives a `FileExistsError`, and when I try to `os.remove(sys.executable)` first, I get `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`. Using `shutil.move()` just has the same problem.

Both work fine on Linux.

How can I replace the currently running, PyInstaller-generated executable from within my Python code?

Comment: In windows whenever you run an executable file, while the process is still running it will not allow you to rename or remove the file.  That is why you are getting those errors.  There is probably a way around this though.